# Layout Help (Ads are covering webview)

Tags: android, android-layout

Right now my ads are covering the top section of my webview and I want them to be displayed above the webview and then the webview starts right under them.. here is my layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.music.promotion.free"
 xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.music.promotion.free"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:background="#000000"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 > 

<WebView android:id="@+id/web_engine"  
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
         android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        />

        <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     ads:adUnitId="a14dc0dc7949bae"
                     ads:adSize="BANNER"/>                               
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/footer" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" style="@android:style/ButtonBar">



<Button android:id="@+id/btnPause" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Pause" />

<Button android:id="@+id/btnPlay" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Play" />
```

I tried this and now they don't seem to be showing up at all..

```
<RelativeLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.music.promotion.free"
 xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.music.promotion.free"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:background="#000000"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 > 
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="50dp"> 
    <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     ads:adUnitId="a14dc0dc7949bae"
                     ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
                     </LinearLayout>

<WebView android:id="@+id/web_engine"  
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
         android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by putting this inside a relative layout:

```
         <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/footer" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" style="@android:style/ButtonBar">

<Button android:id="@+id/btnPause" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Pause" />

<Button android:id="@+id/btnPlay" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Play" />


</LinearLayout>

<WebView android:id="@+id/web_engine"  
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:layout_above="@id/footer" 
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

The ad view has no actual height at view creation. So it will be 0dp tall and then when populated will lay on top of your web view. You need to set aside a spot for the ad in the xml. The Banner ad is 50dp tall. Wrap your com.google.ads.AdView in this linear layout to fix.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="50dp">
```

Comment: do i place that above the webview? will it still chop off part of my webview? i am going to try it right now..

Comment: Put this before your ad view. And end this liner layout after your ad view. You probably then need to move this stuff all above the webview tag.

Comment: You could try setting the android:layout_height="wrap_content" height directly such as: android:layout_height="50dp"

Comment: for the banner or linear layout because the linearlayout is already like that